# Angular download PDF on IOS mostly opens in same tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filesaver.js

I'm using file-saver in my angular application to download a PDF generated in my backend. The library generally works fine on desktop and android. But I don't seem to be able to download a file on IOS. file-saver doesn't, as stated in on the GitHub page, open the blob in a new Page either. it jus opens on the same page (not wanted). Funnily enough it works fine in safari (it opens a dialog that asks me to download and then downloads it without opening it). In any other browser (opera, firefox and chrome) it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried file-saver, downloadJ, creating an anchor tag myself together with the download attribute, using the application/octet-stream mime-type and several other solutions posted on the internet. All of these methods in most browsers just doe nothing or open the PDF blob in the same page instead of downloading it or opening it in a new tab (as file-saver states it would do on IOS).

I'm generating the PDF in a Google Cloud Function. Is there maybe a way to skip the whole client side of things and make the browser download the file directly from there?

Does anyone have another idea on how to download PDF's on mobile IOS (e.g. with a service worker or something)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be a browser PDF extension issue.

Comment: What does that mean? How do I test or maybe even fix that?

Comment: Maybe the browser option bypasses the http request type, check setting like [this one](https://www.trishtech.com/2017/07/set-opera-browser-to-open-pdf-documents-in-default-pdf-viewer/). Also check for the browser's extension settings if anything is there. Also try to deactivate the PDF extension.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution as per new chrome specification https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations

Vanilla  JavaScript

```
public static downloadFile(url: string): void {
     const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
         const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(xmlHttp.response);
         const e = document.createElement('a');
         e.href = blobUrl;
         e.download = blobUrl.substr(blobUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         document.body.appendChild(e);
         e.click();
         document.body.removeChild(e);
       }
     };
     xmlHttp.responseType = 'blob';
     xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
     xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
```

If you're using angular try this.

```
async downloadBrochure(url: string) {
    try {
      const res = await this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
      this.downloadFile(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.body.message);
    }
  }

  downloadFile(data) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const e = document.createElement('a');
    e.href = url;
    e.download = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.click();
    document.body.removeChild(e);
  }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28937291)

Comment: @StefanoA. Full Answer added here. Please remove `devote`.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav! I didn't downvote your answer, just wanted to share some tips to improve the answer.